# Using an Object with ngModel Option Select

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm building a date-time selector in Angular and am having a hard time figuring out how to use an object with `ng-model`. I have a hash of hours with a `name` value of 1-12, each of which has an `AM` and `PM` value. I had no trouble getting `ng-options` to generate an option select with the right names/values, however I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get ng-model to select the correct one from the list based on the initial value I set in my `newPost` model.

I have the following markup in my view:

```
<div>
    <select name="hour" ng-options="hour.value as hour.name for hour in hours" ng-model="newPost.hour"></select>
</div>
```

Then in my controller I build my `currentHour` object like so:

```
var currentHourName = ((new Date()).getHours() + 24) % 12 || 12;
var currentHour = {
    name: currentHourName,
    value: {
        'AM': (((new Date()).getHours() + 24) % 12),
        'PM': (((new Date()).getHours() + 24) % 12) + 12
    }
};

// Ancillary attributes omitted for brevity.
$scope.newPost = {
    hour: currentHour
};


$scope.hours = [
    {name: 1, value: {'AM': 0,'PM': 12}},
    {name: 2, value: {'AM': 1,'PM': 13}},
    {name: 3, value: {'AM': 2,'PM': 14}},
    {name: 4, value: {'AM': 3,'PM': 15}},
    {name: 5, value: {'AM': 4,'PM': 16}},
    {name: 6, value: {'AM': 5,'PM': 17}},
    {name: 7, value: {'AM': 6,'PM': 18}},
    {name: 8, value: {'AM': 7,'PM': 19}},
    {name: 9, value: {'AM': 8,'PM': 20}},
    {name: 10, value: {'AM': 9,'PM': 21}},
    {name: 11, value: {'AM': 10,'PM': 22}},
    {name: 12, value: {'AM': 11,'PM': 23}}
];
```

What I'd like to know is how I can make this work with `ng-model`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `track by` inside the `ng-options`. Except this angular does not know how to compare the equality between your `ng-model` and options. But if you provide the `track by` field name, it'll use this field to check equality.

Here is a working example in plunker: [Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/WBDRHH2ehsnZiy2gf21V)

Comment: I accepted your answer because it works for my case in theory. In practice I couldn't get it to work as I wanted though. I ended up cooking up a hack last night that works. The only downside to my approach is that if a user changed the meridiem, the hour changes. I changed the expression to `ng-options="hour.value[newPost.meridiem] as hour.name for hour in hours" ng-model="newPost.hour.value[newPost.meridiem]"`. The main advantage of this is that `newPost.hour` is now an integer instead of an object, which makes preprocessing the form submission easier.

Comment: Can you please provide a plunker on what problem you are facing so that I can try on that?